# can't get google maps api key

Tags: android, google-maps

I have windows 7 and it seems that I can't get api key ! I've tried so much !

I opened the cmd and entered:

```
 keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore D:\avd\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

and yet it says to me:

> 'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,  operable
>   program or batch file.

I've also tried like that:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\java.exe" keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore D:\avd\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

and it says:

```
Could not find or load main class keytool
```

**hope someone can help me I am very Desperate for an answer !**

Answer (score 0):

The dollar sign is not part of what you need to paste into your terminal.  You should start with `keytool` on forward.  In the example the dollar sign is showing the beginning of the prompt (which is how it looks on Unix/Mac terminals).

`keytool` is an executable that is part of the Java SDK.  The location of the bin file must either be added to your terminal's path or you have to run it using the full path to the file.  Typically, on Windows the Java binaries are located at `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin` or something similar.  You were close with your second guess in this case, but `keytool` is not a command you pass to `java.exe`...it is an executable itself in the same directory.

HTH

Comment: i also tried without the dollar sign in the both ways ive showed

Comment: And what was the result in those cases?

Comment: in the first way it show:


    'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

and in the second way it show:

 Could not find or load main class keytool

Comment: Edited answer with more info.

Comment: tnxxxxxx your answer and the other guy answer helps me to find the answer , solved :) !

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\keytool -v -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore D:\avd\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

or

Just copy the debug.keystore file to the same folder as keytool and execute the below in command prompt

```
keytool -v -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore D:\avd\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

Comment: "'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." :\

Comment: tnxxxxxx your answer and the other guy answer helps me to find the answer , solved :) !

Answer (score 0):

Those are the steps through the Command Prompt that worked for me :

> cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin keytool -list -alias
>   androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\ {username}.android\debug.keystore
>   -storepass android -keypass android